# How Can I handle dialog window to click on button in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I am trying to click on OK button in dialog box. How can I find xpath to find the button and click to close the window. It is not in any Iframe.
Here is my Code:

```html
    `<div id="YesNoDialogBox" class="dialogbox errorDialog firepath-
 matching-node" style="display: block;">
 <div class="errWarnMsg">
<div class="popupHeaderContainer">
<div class="imgicon"><img src="/web/images/error.png" class="vMiddle"  
tabindex=""></div>
   <h1>Warning message</h1>
   <!-- Start: Warehouse change confirmation popup --><a href="#" id="close" class="closeClass warehouseCancel" tabindex=""> 
   <img src="/web/images/close.png" class="closeIcon errWarnIcoClose" tabindex="">
   </a>
   <div class="clear"></div> 
   <div class="msgBody paddingTopBtm2 textLeft padLeft10 warehouseText" style="">
    <span class="warningText" id="errorTextWarning">
     Please Confirm to change warehouse
     <br><br>
        Do you want to continue?
    </span>  
   </div>
   <div class="msgBody paddingTopBtm2 textLeft padLeft10 customerText" style="display:none">
  <span class="warningText" id="errorTextWarning">
   Please Confirm to change Customer
   <br><br>
      Do you want to continue?
  </span>     
   </div>
   <div id="dialogboxNav" class="padding10 textLeft padLeft10 marginleft40">  
  <button class="enterSubmit btnInactive" name="btn_delete" id="warehouseOk" tabindex="">Yes</button>
  
  <a href="javascript:;" id="cancelDialog" class="formblue_link closeClass warehouseCancel" tabindex="">No</a>
   </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>`<div id="YesNoDialogBox" class="dialogbox errorDialog firepath-
     matching-node" style="display: block;">
     <div class="errWarnMsg">
    <div class="popupHeaderContainer">
      <div class="imgicon"><img src="/web/images/error.png" class="vMiddle" tabindex=""></div>
    <h1>Warning message</h1>
    <!-- Start: Warehouse change confirmation popup --><a href="#" id="close" class="closeClass warehouseCancel" tabindex=""> 
    <img src="/web/images/close.png" class="closeIcon errWarnIcoClose" tabindex="">
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div class="msgBody paddingTopBtm2 textLeft padLeft10 warehouseText" style="">
     <span class="warningText" id="errorTextWarning">
      Please Confirm to change warehouse
      <br><br>
        Do you want to continue?
     </span>  
    </div>
    <div class="msgBody paddingTopBtm2 textLeft padLeft10 customerText" style="display:none">
   <span class="warningText" id="errorTextWarning">
    Please Confirm to change Customer
    <br><br>
      Do you want to continue?
   </span>     
    </div>
    <div id="dialogboxNav" class="padding10 textLeft padLeft10 marginleft40">  
   <button class="enterSubmit btnInactive" name="btn_delete" id="warehouseOk" tabindex="">Yes</button>
      
      <a href="javascript:;" id="cancelDialog" class="formblue_link closeClass warehouseCancel" tabindex="">No</a>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple yes/no buttons are present in provided HTML, which one do you want to locate and click??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're pasting same dialog window HTML two times. Assuming there is only one dialog window.

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until dialog window visible and enable to click desired element as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

- If you want to click on `Yes` button try as :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("warehouseOk"))).click();
  ```
- If you want to click on `No` button try as :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cancelDialog"))).click();
  ```
- If you want to click on `Close` button try as :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("close"))).click();
  ```

**Note** :- There is no need to use `xpath` locator, desired element could be locate easily using `By.id()` locator.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to match by the ID:

```
//button[@id="warehouseOk"]
```

[This article](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/xpath-locator-examples/) cites some useful examples of HTML XPath queries.